# Install app with no install instructions

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I've unpacked tar.gz file and there was no instructions to installation. Only executable file that starts a program.

Is there any way to "install" this program to system, or the only way is to make a shortcut to it?

Comment: Could you post program name or name of file tar.gz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an application requires simply unpack the file and run the file to start the program, you must move the directory to /opt.

Then in order to add your launcher to the Unity bar on the left, you have to place your launcher at /usr/share/applications/

.desktop files are files for launching links or applications.

To create one, you can use nano to manually create a desktop file.

```
sudo su
nano /usr/share/applications/myprogram.destop
```

The file should contain lines similar to these:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.6
Name=ProgramName
Comment=Your comment is this
Exec=/opt/ProgramName/file
Icon=/opt/ProgramName/Icons/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Control + O, save file. Control + X, close nano.

You can now do right click on your file --- Properties ---- Permissions ---- Allow executing file as program.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can safely copy the program to /usr/local/bin/ (just to be safe). Only do that if you are sure that the program runs on your architecture.